# Read all log files at one go in logstash config file

Tags: elasticsearch, logstash, logstash-configuration, elk

How to read all log files under the different subdirectories inside more sub-directories.
List of log files under 2 folders (message and RSI) in 3 sub-directories under sample_data directory. I want to read all the content of log files at once dynamically. the config file path should automatically read all log files from the subdirectories within the sample_data main directory
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Mlj1Y.png)

The path I tried but it is taking only one log file not all log files
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oPPcY.png)

The yml file to define the volume source and destination
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vn7LR.png)

Comment: try path like /usr/share/logstash/sample_data/**/*.log and check.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.